# wrapping a method causes the method to be undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I have some strange issue : if I run

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    http_basic_authenticate_with name: "test", password: "test"
```

it works fine. But if I put this

```
before_filter authenticate_incoming

  def authenticate_incoming
    http_basic_authenticate_with name: "hi", password: "ho"
  end
```

I get `undefined method http_basic_authenticate_with`. Where am I joint wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the source code of `http_basic_authenticate_with` is

```
def http_basic_authenticate_with(options = {})
            before_filter(options.except(:name, :password, :realm)) do
              authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic(options[:realm] || "Application") do |name, password|
                name == options[:name] && password == options[:password]
              end
            end
          end
```

So you see that it is implementing `before_filer`. So what you should do is using something like (you can also store some `session` login data ;))

```
def authenticate_incoming
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |name, password|
          if name == 'hi' && password == 'ho'
            session[:logged_in] = true
            return true
          else
            return false
          end
        end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`http_basic_authenticate_with` is a class method and `authenticate_incoming` is an instance method. You could do `self.class.http_basic_authenticate_with` but that doesn't make a whole lot of sense to do in a `before_filter`. What's your goal? Maybe I can help you think through how to acomplish it.